# CSS - Same Height Containers

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to replicate the following in CSS and can't seem to get it right. I've tried using table cell, but it appears that the bottom progress bar's margin seems to collapse.

The paragraph tag has to be the same size, and vertically and horizontally centered.

Could anyone suggest a way of doing this, I'm starting to struggle.

Thanks

https://jsbin.com/rukodo/2/edit?html,css,output

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you restructure your code the way which makes text blocks having one parent. I have modified your code: https://jsbin.com/wujezugima/1/edit?html,css,output 
That way the larger text block will extend the height of the parent block `.container` which will align the other text block properly

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use this code for same height.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function equalHeight(group) { 
    tallest = 0; 
    group.each(function() { 
        thisHeight = $(this).height(); 
        if(thisHeight > tallest) { 
            tallest = thisHeight; 
        } 
    }); 
    group.height(tallest); 
} 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    equalHeight($(".EqHeightDiv")); 
}); 
</script>
<div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff</div><div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff</div><div class="EqHeightDiv" style="float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:10px;">Here is some stuff</div>
```